# Symfony2 directly call actions of controllers without routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes, frameworks

Currently I am working on a new project using Symfony2.
Coming from Zend I really enjoyed being able to call controllers and their actions directly in the url like so: `http://www.example.com/dog/bark/loudly`

And then without having to write up a route, the framwork would call the DogController's barkAction and pass it the argument `loudly`.

Unfortunately Symfony2 doesn't seem to like to do this, I did some googling, looked at the documentation, but it was to no avail.
I would love to know how to achieve this in Symfony2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own route loader like it is explained [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html).

Then use [ReflexionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) to list your actions.

You can also iterate on each controller with [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php)

Example :

```
// src/AppBundle/Routing/ExtraLoader.php
namespace AppBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class ExtraLoader extends Loader
{
    private $loaded = false;

    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        if (true === $this->loaded) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Do not add the "extra" loader twice');
        }

        $routes = new RouteCollection();

        $controllerName = 'Default';

        $reflexionController = new \ReflectionClass("AppBundle\\Controller\\".$controllerName."Controller");

        foreach($reflexionController->getMethods() as $reflexionMethod){
            if($reflexionMethod->isPublic() && 1 === preg_match('/^([a-ZA-Z]+)Action$/',$reflexionMethod->getName(),$matches)){
                $actionName = $matches[1];
                $routes->add(
                    strtolower($controllerName) & '_' & strtolower($actionName), // Route name
                    new Route(
                        strtolower($controllerName) & '_' & strtolower($actionName), // Path
                        array('_controller' => 'AppBundle:'.$controllerName.':'.$actionName),   // Defaults
                        array() // requirements
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        $this->loaded = true;

        return $routes;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return 'extra' === $type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every framework has it's own characteristics. To me, rough example below is the easiest way so you should be able to call it via `http://www.my_app.com/dog/bark/loudly`

Define controllers as services. [How to Define Controllers as Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html)

```
namespace MyAppBundle\Controller\DogController;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/dog", service="my_application.dog_controller")
 */
class DogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/bark/{how}")
     */
    public function barkAction($how)
    {
        return new Response('Dog is barking '.$how);
    }
}
```

Service definition

```
services:
    my_application.dog_controller:
        class: MyAppBundle\Controller\DogController
```